# jquery ajax not working after str.replace

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a jQuery ajax that doesn't work ONLY when there's another jQuery function using javascript's `replace` function. why is this happening?

note:

1. this only happens when running on Internet Explorer. It's working fine on Firefox
2. I'm very new to jQuery (have only been learning jQuery for 2 days). so please be gentle with me :)

this is the html file:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('koneksi.php');
include('function.php');

unset($_SESSION['cust']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <script src="jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <title>CSS MenuMaker</title>
</head>
<body>
                <table class="width100 padding5 border_black" id="tabel_input_master" name="tabel_input_master">
                    <tr class="my_form">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <div>
                                <div style="float:left; width:60px">Telepon</div>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    id="cust_telp"
                                    name="cust_telp"
                                    style="width:200px;"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div id="cust_detail" name="cust_detail">
                                <div style="float:left; width:60px">Name</div>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    id="cust_name"
                                    name="cust_name"
                                    style="width:200px;"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

this is the content of script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cust_telp").on("change",function(){
        var myurl = "show_cust.php?q=" + $(this).val();
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: myurl,
            type: "GET"
        });
        request.done(function(result){
            var cust = JSON.parse(result);
            if (cust[0].nama == '') {
                $("#cust_name").val('');
                $("#cust_name").prop('readonly',false);
            }else{
                $("#cust_name").val(cust[0].name);
                $("#cust_name").prop('readonly', true);
            }
        });
    });

    // when I put this script here, the ajax call on [change] event stopped working
    $("#cust_telp").on("keyup",function(){
        var temp = $(this).val();
        temp = temp.replace(/\D/g,'');
        $("#cust_telp").val(temp);
    });
});
```

but when I replace the keyup script with this one below, the ajax call works normally again

```
$("#cust_telp").on("keyup",function(){
        var temp = $(this).val();
        alert(temp);
    });
```

here's the show_cust.php file

```
<?php
session_start();
include('koneksi.php');
include('function.php');

$q = (isset($_GET['q'])) ? $_GET['q'] : '';
$outp = '';
unset($cust); 
$cust = array();

if ($q != '') {
    $sql = "select * from customer where telp1 = '".$q."' or telp2 = '".$q."'";
    $query = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $cust = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    unset($_SESSION['cust']);
    $_SESSION['cust'] = $cust;

    $outp =  "[";
    $outp .= '{"name":"' . $cust["name"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"address":"' . $cust["address"] . '"}';
    $outp .= "]";
}

echo $outp;
?>
```

Comment: I think what is happening is, the change event is triggered when the value is commited, so during that phase it checks whether the previously committed value is the same as current value if so the change event is not  triggered, but since we are setting the value of programatically it is updated in the commited property so when the blur happens there is no difference between the committed and current value(not posted as an answer since I can't find a reference material)

Comment: You also have a closing </body> and </html> tag right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution will be to prevent the default nature of keys to prevent the unwanted keys like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cust_telp").on("change", function() {
    snippet.log('changed: ' + this.value)
  });

  // when I put this script here, the ajax call on [change] event stopped working
  $("#cust_telp").on("keypress", function(e) {
    return e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57;
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="width100 padding5 border_black" id="tabel_input_master" name="tabel_input_master">
  <tr class="my_form">
    <td colspan="2">
      <div>
        <div style="float:left; width:60px">Telepon</div>
        <input type="text" id="cust_telp" name="cust_telp" style="width:200px;" />
      </div>
      <div id="cust_detail" name="cust_detail">
        <div style="float:left; width:60px">Name</div>
        <input type="text" id="cust_name" name="cust_name" style="width:200px;" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks so much! the keypress part did the trick even better than replace because with replace, the input key still shows for a split second. I don't need to use the snippet object atm though..

Comment: @dapidmini no.. that is used just to demonstrate that the change event is triggered